# Angular view update with variable is slower than native getElementById

Tags: angular

I have a service emits events every 5 milliseconds and I have to update my angular view component which contains a timer label.

I tried two methods to update my view:

Label 1: a simple variable

```
<div>{{timer}}</div>

this.timer= Date.now() - startTime;
```

Label 2: retrieve a div by `getElementById` and set the innerHTML

```
<div id="timer"></div>

document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = (Date.now() - startTime).toString();
```

This is the result:

[image]

As you can see, both labels showing the updated current time but while `Label 2` is running smoothly, `Label 1` is updated slowly losing milliseconds.

Can you tell me if it is wrong to go with `getElementById` or if this is a known Angular problem?

Comment: Are you running on default change-detection or on push? https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

Comment: I think this is a normal behaviour : you used two way data binding and every 5ms angular must detect changes so when he try to do some calculs a new value comes and this is why you angular updated the value slowly.
In the second Label you used the native dom api to update element and this is why it's faster than the fisrt.

Comment: I tried on stackblitz and both ways have the same refresh speed: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gczmgk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts